# How to print common values from two different overlapping ranges without repetition

Tags: perl

I have the following code. I am trying to print all common values from @arr2 and @arr4 without repetition. The expected output should be 5,6,7,8,9,13,14,15,16,17,18. I am not getting how to put a condition in a loop to avoid repetition and why $i is not printing in this code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @arr2 = ( 1 .. 10, 5 .. 15, 10 .. 20 );
my @arr4 = ( 5 .. 9, 13 .. 18 );

foreach my $line1 (@arr2) {
    my ( $from1, $to1 ) = split( /\.\./, $line1 );
    #print "$to1\n";
    foreach my $line2 (@arr4) {
        my ( $from2, $to2 ) = split( /\.\./, $line2 );
        for ( my $i = $from1; $i <= $to1; $i++ ) {
            for ( my $j = $from2; $j <= $to2; $j++ ) {
                if ( $i == $j ) {
                    print "$i \n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Jonathan has pointed out, you appear to misunderstanding the nature of your data because you don't recognize the [Range Operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) used to construct lists.

```
my @array = (1 .. 10);
print "@array\n";
```

Outputs

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Once you recognize that, then you just need to be pointed to the following:

- [perlfaq4 - How can I remove duplicate elements from a list or array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3f)
- [perlfaq4 - How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays%3f-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays%3f)

Combined to form:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr2 = ( 1 .. 10, 5 .. 15, 10 .. 20 );
my @arr4 = ( 5 .. 9, 13 .. 18 );

my %seen;
$seen{$_}++ for uniq(@arr2), uniq(@arr4);

my @intersection = sort { $a <=> $b } grep { $seen{$_} == 2 } keys %seen;

print "@intersection\n";

sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    $seen{$_}++ for @_;
    return keys %seen;
}
```

Outputs:

```
5 6 7 8 9 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step to understanding your problem is to understand your data — the arrays do not hold what you think they hold.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @arr2=(1..10,5..15,10..20);
my @arr4=(5..9,13..18);

print "arr2: @arr2\n";
print "arr4: @arr4\n";
```

The output from this is:

```
arr2: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
arr4: 5 6 7 8 9 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

This shows that your code trying to split a string on `..` is going to fail horribly.

One of the most basic debugging techniques is printing out the data you've actually got to ensure it matches what you think you should have.  Here, that basic printing would have shown that the input data is not in the format you expected.

Comment: Sub contents could also written as `print "$name: @arr\n";`

Comment: Like the comment said, TMTOWTDI.  But I agree.